# How to run a stored procedure with param and store result as a record set in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, parameters, recordset, procedure

I wasn't able to find a question/answer that covers this fully hence why I am asking. What I need to do is run a stored procedure that takes 1 parameter. It will return a set of results which I need to store in a record set. I plan to loop through this recordset later. I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to older asp, but here is what I have to far:

```
dim myConn
Set myConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
myConn.Open = ("DSN=example-dsn;SERVER=example-server;DATABASE=example-db;UID=user;PWD=pass;")

dim oStoredProc : Set oStoredProc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With oStoredProc
    .ActiveConnection = myConn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "myStoredProcedure"
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@PARAM1", ADODB.adInteger, ADODB.adParamInput, 10, 2012))
    Dim rs : Set rs = .Execute() 

End With

// Will loop through it here.
```

My guess is that I'm not setting up the recordset right, but like I said, I'm not really sure. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424752/asp-classic-recordset-object-vs-command-object

Comment: I actually read that and based most of what I did on it, however I can't seem to get it quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright there were a few things I was doing wrong but here is what ended up working for me. First off it turns out I didn't need a parameter passed in, but that was not the problem anyway. One of the main issues what that 'adCmdStoredProc' wasn't recognized, which is odd because I've seen it used everywhere else, but replacing it with it's corresponding value, 4, did work.

```
dim myConn, cmd

Set myConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
myConn.Open = ("DSN=[BLAH];SERVER=[SERVER];DATABASE=[BLAH];UID=[User];PWD=[Pass];")

dim oStoredProc : Set oStoredProc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oStoredProc.CommandType = 4 
oStoredProc.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
oStoredProc.ActiveConnection = myConn
// Add parameters here if needed.

Dim rs 
Set rs = oStoredProc.Execute()

// I Loop through here

rs.Close
myConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set oStoredProc = Nothing
Set myConn = Nothing
```

I hope this helps if anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make sure your result set is the correct object

```
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Then you will use the [open method](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_open.asp) I think it works something like this:

```
   rs.Open oStoredProc
```

Then use the other members of the [Record Set object](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp) to loop through the results.

Comment: How is this different from getting the recordset from the Command's execute method?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim rsStk As New ADODB.Recordset

Set rsStk = cnnPck.Execute("SP_JOB_ALL '" & Trim(te_Item) & "'")

Set Recordset= CONNECTION .Execute()
```

This one is simple way to do this thing